# is there a way to shorten this change handler that uses hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With class based components you could use the computed properties to in order to use one single handler for several inputs with the help of an id attribute like this:

```
function handleChange(evt) {
  const value = evt.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state,
    [evt.target.name]: value
  });
}
```

This is thebest I caome up with but im sure there must be a shorter way:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'name') setName(e.target.value)
    if (e.target.id === 'genre') setGenre(e.target.value)
    if (e.target.id === 'description') setDescription(e.target.value)
  }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have create an object in the `useState` and update just like the first example.

```
// Declare the state with a object default value
const [state, setState] = useState({})

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }))
}
```

If you can't change the `useState` and have a very **strong** reason to have these 3 separeted `useState`s, you could create an object that returns the 3 functions based on the `e.target.id`

```
const updater = {
    name: setName,
    genre: setGenre,
    description: setDescription,
}
```

And when updating you do

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const updateValue = updater[e.target.id]

    if (updateValue) {
        updateValue(e.target.value)
    }
    else {
        // No function to update found
        // Do something else
    }
}
```